# How to Define row id for <h:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf-2

Is there is any way to define row id for h:panelGrid ?If we define a id for h:panelGrid then it wil become table's id in the output html.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you add more details? What have you done, what is the expected value and what value is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<h:panelGrid>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html) doesn't provide for a way of setting ids of individual rows. Instead, its attribute `rowClasses` is designed to control setting of CSS classes to the rows. Typically, this attribute is used to setup alternating formatting of rows.

Documentation tells that `rowClasses` accepts a "comma-delimited list of CSS style classes that will be applied to the rows of this table" and that "a space separated list of classes may also be specified for any individual row". The styles specified in the attribute will then be applied to each row in the table.

The example of setting up alternative rows with `<h:panelGrid>`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow"> ... </h:panelGrid>
```

Though, if the requirement of setting id to an individual row is strict, you could consider using Primefaces' [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf), where you can nest [`<p:row>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/row.html) tags that have an `id` property.